# download download.csv file from internet explorer

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Team,

URL=https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain

i want to download download.csv file from internet explorer but manually save requiring to do in below given code, can someone improvise the same.

```
Code-

Sub Get_Option_Chain_Data_IE()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLELements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Set HTMLElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("downloadOCTable")

    HTMLElement.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We can press **Alt+S** to save the download files in IE. So in VBA, we can use `Application.SendKeys "%{s}"` to simulate the keystroke to click the **Save** button. You can also refer to [SendKeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement).

The sample code snippet is like below. I test it and it works well:

```
Set HTMLElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("downloadOCTable")
HTMLElement.Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
Application.SendKeys "%{s}"
```